# White to play and checkmate in two moves

Tags: problems

It’s White to play and checkmate in two moves.

This puzzle was created by Frank Healey, and published in 5 Family Herald on 7/17/1858.

```
7R/1B1N4/8/3r4/1K2k3/8/5Q2/8 w - - 0 1
```

Answer (score 35):

Use the fact that the rook is pinned, and that the king has few squares left;
I'm thinking that 1.Rd8 Kd3 (only possible move) 2.Nc5# should be the solution.

```
[White "NN"]
[Black "NN"]
[FEN "7R/1B1N4/8/3r4/1K2k3/8/5Q2/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Rd8 Kd3 2.Nc5#
```

Comment: Beautiful. Without seeing the idea behind the final mating position you wouldn't even consider Rd8 as a candidate first move.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Black is not in check, but still only has one move:

[image]

Check mate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move the rook onto the same row as the king, king moves to the only possible square, checkmate by moving the bishop to a6?

1. Rh4, Kd3 2. Ba6#

Comment: 2. Ba6+ isn't a checkmate, Black can reply with 2...Rb5+.